# Save password prompt disappears when changing location

Tags: passwords, location, save, reload, prompt

I'm running a login form, which - in case of success - forwards the user to a specific page via JS *location.href*. The browsers correctly recognize the form as a login form and offer to save the password. Now only in Google Chrome, the prompt disappears once the location changes. So the prompt is visible for just a split second, making it impossible to save the password.
Is there any solution for this? Refreshing after login success is a common thing, so there should be a way to fix this..
**Edit:**
This is what the form looks like:

```
<form id="loginform" action="process.php" target="processframe" method="POST">
<input id="login_name" name="name" type="text" placeholder="Username"><br>
<input id="login_password" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"><br>
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
<iframe src="" id="processframe" name="processframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
```

So the request is processed in an iframe. *process.php* then calls a javascript function:

```
window.setTimeout("parent.loginsuccess()", 1000);
```

The loginsuccess() function:

```
function loginsuccess()
{
location.href="/home.php";
}
```

Comment: Please show us some code.